# I have a graph with data from 1999, and I want to add another line which is only about 6 months long, how can I do that?

Tags: microsoft-excel

My line plots the data series from 1999 to now. The other line I want to plot is about half a year in 2001. How can I insert this new line into the same graph I have for the other longer data series from 1999 to now.

Answer (score 1):

If this suits:

[image: Example chart]

then:

1. Select source data (here `A1:C20`).
2. Insert desired layout (here Charts, Line, Line with Markers)

rest should be automatic!

Comment: If you go to the Edit Data dialog for the chart, click on Hidden and Empty Cells in the bottom left corner, and choose the Connect Points with Lines option, so there's no gap in the red lines of Series A.